# Deploy django to digitalocean

Tags: django

I  use django to deploy to digitalocean, but I have used the runtime file to modify the python version, but after deployment, the following message still appears.

```
2023-10-24T09:29:44.757072536Z [34m╭────────────[34m[30m[44m git repo clone [0m[0m[34m───────────╼[0m
2023-10-24T09:29:44.757101317Z [34m│[0m [34m › fetching app source code[0m
2023-10-24T09:29:44.757106815Z [34m│[0m => Selecting branch "main"
2023-10-24T09:29:47.813070835Z [34m│[0m => Checking out commit "8e73926565789603a85297bedda678f76a1c3c0b"
2023-10-24T09:29:47.894764681Z [34m│[0m 
2023-10-24T09:29:47.907242184Z [34m│[0m [32m ✔ cloned repo to [35m/workspace[0m[0m
2023-10-24T09:29:47.985763173Z [34m╰────────────────────────────────────────╼[0m
2023-10-24T09:29:47.985784026Z 
2023-10-24T09:29:48.241850731Z [34m › configuring build-time app environment variables:[0m
2023-10-24T09:29:48.241872928Z      DEBUG DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS DATABASE_URL
2023-10-24T09:29:48.241876096Z 
2023-10-24T09:29:48.427492632Z [34m╭────────────[34m[30m[44m buildpack detection [0m[0m[34m───────────╼[0m
2023-10-24T09:29:48.473752383Z [34m│[0m [34m › using Ubuntu 22.04 stack[0m
2023-10-24T09:29:48.956739202Z [34m│[0m Detected the following buildpacks suitable to build your app:
2023-10-24T09:29:48.956762601Z [34m│[0m 
2023-10-24T09:29:48.956766764Z [34m│[0m    digitalocean/python-appdetect  v0.0.3    
2023-10-24T09:29:48.956769954Z [34m│[0m    heroku/python                  v2.234.4  (Python)
2023-10-24T09:29:48.956772899Z [34m│[0m    digitalocean/procfile          v0.0.4    (Procfile)
2023-10-24T09:29:48.956775998Z [34m│[0m    digitalocean/custom            v0.1.2    (Custom Build Command)
2023-10-24T09:29:48.956778905Z [34m│[0m 
2023-10-24T09:29:48.956782304Z [34m│[0m For documentation on the buildpacks used to build your app, please see:
2023-10-24T09:29:48.956785169Z [34m│[0m 
2023-10-24T09:29:48.956787941Z [34m│[0m    Python  v2.234.4  https://do.co/apps-buildpack-python
2023-10-24T09:29:48.961924274Z [34m╰─────────────────────────────────────────────╼[0m
2023-10-24T09:29:48.961940790Z 
2023-10-24T09:29:48.965795463Z [34m╭────────────[34m[30m[44m app build [0m[0m[34m───────────╼[0m
2023-10-24T09:29:49.159322638Z [34m│[0m -----> Using Python version specified in runtime.txt
2023-10-24T09:29:49.853946733Z [34m│[0m  !     Requested runtime 'python-3.12.0' is not available for this stack (heroku-22).
2023-10-24T09:29:49.853971556Z [34m│[0m  !     For supported versions, see: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support
2023-10-24T09:29:49.856706598Z [34m│[0m [31;1mERROR: [0mfailed to build: exit status 1
2023-10-24T09:29:50.045411097Z [34m│[0m 
2023-10-24T09:29:50.052507334Z [34m│[0m 
2023-10-24T09:29:50.053059713Z [34m│[0m For documentation on the buildpacks used to build your app, please see:
2023-10-24T09:29:50.053303402Z [34m│[0m 
2023-10-24T09:29:50.053506585Z [34m│[0m    Python  v2.234.4  https://do.co/apps-buildpack-python
2023-10-24T09:29:50.053746044Z [34m│[0m 
2023-10-24T09:29:50.067669520Z [34m│[0m [31m ✘ build failed[0m
```

There is a way to first modify the runtime version to a suitable one, such as python3.9, but the Django environment itself uses Python 3.8.3.